# AttributedString on a CollectionView cell is not displaying string value

Tags: swift, string, uicollectionview, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a UICollectinViewCell with a label set to attributedString.

Inside cellForItem, I cast a simple string to an NSAttributedString so that I can set the UILabel's attributedText property.

The string `"Attributed String Text"` only appears if I scroll the CollectionView. If I do not scroll, `"Label"` appears, as that's the text that is set in IB. If I keep the UILabel as plain, the correct text appears just fine.

```
// cellForItemAt
let string = "Attributed String Text"
let mutableAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string)
cell.subName.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
```

**How can I get the attributedText to show without having to scroll the CollectionView?**

Comment: Where you set the delegate and dataSource ?

Comment: I set the delegate and dataSource in viewDidLoad.

Comment: can you post full context

Comment: Try `cell.subName.text = "Something"` instead. If you don't see something, that's not related to NSAttributedString, but `UICollectionView`. But we need more context, full code of cellForItemAt, a reuse issue?

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I will try that. I will post more code from the project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I believe it may be an Xcode bug. Nothing was wrong with my code. Normal (plain) text UILabel was displaying proper text just fine. When I switched it to attributed UILabel, the text *stopped* displaying with no other code changes.

After digging around for a while, I found this thread: [Label text in UICollectionViewCell not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185535/label-text-in-uicollectionviewcell-not-updating) where user Jacksonsox was having a similar issue.

In Interface Builder, I removed the connection to the UILabel that wasn't updating, deleted the UILabel, re-added a new label, re-connected it, set it to Attributed text, and the text now shows up just fine. Again, no code changes made. Only changes were in IB.

I hope this helps others who are experiencing similar issues.